# FaceDetection Bounding Box questions

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection

I have developed a face-detection android application which is able to detect faces and draw a bounding box around the person's face when the face is being detected. But for now I was wondering if it is possible to get the coordinates (x and y axis) of the bounding box or any methods to determine the coordinates of the bounding box. Does anyone of you have any suggestions on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course it is possible. You should probably show the code that you're using, otherwise noone will be able to give a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am forwarding an url which contains the J2me code for Face Detector.
You can check the logic on J2me & implement the same on Android. 
Hopefully the article helps us to get the co-ordinate for the Bounding box .

**https://labs.ericsson.com/apis/face-detector/documentation**

Kindly revert for any clarifications.